# How to get a table to make a new column based on user data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need this to make a new column, and when it populates it with data, if male add 'yes' if female insert 'no'.

```
SELECT * FROM ADD_FACULTY_OVERRIDE
WHEN "GENDER" ='Male' INSERT 'YES' AS "Financial Aid"
```

Comment: ....okay, I have to ask, why are you blanket giving all guys financial aid, and denying it to all women (ignoring all people who may claim some other gender)?  This seems like it would make you wide open for a discrimination lawsuit.

Comment: Ha, I didn't spot that @Clockwork - it does seem to be a discriminatory query, now you mention it. But we don't know the context of the question, I guess...

Comment: @clockwork I'm just using this as an example for a question my teacher asked me not in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to avoid using `SELECT *`, it's costly when running queries, be explicit with your columns as a rule of thumb.  Here's what you want:

```
SELECT EAGLE_ID
    ,DEPT_ID
    ,LAST_NAME
    ,FIRST_NAME
    ,MIDDLE_NAME
    ,GENDER
    ,BIRTHDATE
    ,ETHNICITY
    ,TENURE
    ,SHORT_TITLE
    ,FULL_TIME
    ,EMAIL
    ,CASE 
        WHEN GENDER = 'Male'
            THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN GENDER = 'Female'
            THEN 'No'
        ELSE ''
        END AS [Financial_Aid]
FROM ADD_FACULTY_OVERRIDE
```

Comment: A good use of CASE; my main concern, though, is in the future, perhaps a male may need "No" as financial aid, or a female may have "Yes" for financial aid.

Comment: That's a very good point.  Not sure what his needs would be going forward but for the information we have been given, this is the solution.

Comment: select 
 "EAGLE_ID",
 "DEPT_ID",
 "LAST_NAME",
 "FIRST_NAME",
 "MIDDLE_NAME",
 "GENDER",
 "BIRTHDATE",
 "ETHNICITY",
 "TENURE",
 "SHORT_TITLE",
 "FULL_TIME",
 "EMAIL", are my other collums how can i encorprate this into these (gender comes from here)

Comment: Updated, see above answer now.

Comment: WHEN i add it it gives me an ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error help

Comment: Is this an Oracle system or SQL?  You indicated by your tag that this is sql.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the entire thing. Including the `FROM` statement?

Comment: SQL is what im useing

Comment: im using oracle application express and using a report

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, this syntax should work.

Comment: @Kris, do the `[]` delimiters work outside of SQL Server? I don't think the OP mentioned what database they are using, so SQL Server cannot be assumed. The tag "sql" means the query language, not Microsoft's database server.

Comment: Kris is right but you don't use brackets use double quotes like this "Financial_Aid"

Comment: @user3821879: on Stack Overflow you can expect people to edit your question and/or assist, as they so choose - everyone here is a volunteer. What is the remaining part you are stuck on? Seems like Kris has answered it, save the delimiters issue that you're already aware of. And you've accepted his answer, too - a state that normally indicates that you regard your issue as resolved.

Comment: If you still have problems, please edit your question containing your new SQL attempt, so we can see where you are. Don't forget to consult the docs for your database system, now you are aware of `CASE`.

Comment: Kris had meetings and was unable to respond. Sorry. I'm a full time DBA and gotta make sure the work is getting done.

Comment: Ok sorry, you were right this solved my problem thanks for your time and effort.